# Assume that a part of ∆ABC around vertex A is not visible. Describe how to find the angle bisector of ∠CAB.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Assume that a part of ∆ABC around vertex A is not visible. Describe how to find
the angle bisector of ∠CAB.

I have no idea how to begin this problem. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: find its intercept on $BC$ and one other point known to be on the bisector.

Comment: So, are you saying to position the triangle in a cartesian plane?

Comment: How does one known angle bisector would help me find the angle bisector of vertex A? Should I look at the concurrency?

Comment: Cartesian plane - not necessarily, what I say is that you can find those two points geometrically without using the hidden vertex $A$. Concurrency - yes, that's relevant.

Comment: So you are saying to find the angle bisectos of angle B and angle C. Then their intersection will indicate the angle bisector of angle A?

Comment: Their intersection will give you one point on the bisector of $A$, indeed. For a second point, that's already been answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may exploit the following property of the angle bisector through $A$: for any point $P$ on it, the distance of $P$ from the $AB$-side equals the distance of $P$ from the $AC$-side. Just find two distinct points with such property in the visible part and join them to get the wanted line.

[image]

You may take $P=I$ as the intersection of the internal angle bisectors from $B$ and $C$ and $Q=I_A$ as the intersection of the external angle bisectors from $B$ and $C$, for instance.

An alternative approach through triangle similarities:
[image]

1. Take $B'\in AB$ close to $B$ and let $C'\in AC$ such that $B'C'\parallel BC$;
2. Let $C''\in BC$ be such that $B' C''\parallel AC$;
3. Let $J$ the point in which the angle bisector of $\widehat{BB'C''}$ meets the $BC$-side
    and $K$ the projection of $J$ on $B'C''$;
4. Let $L=BK\cap AC$ and $N\in BC$ be such that $LN\parallel KJ$;
5. The parallel to $B'J$ through $L$ is the wanted angle bisector.

A third approach:

[image]

1. Let $B'$ and $C'$ like before, let $M$ be the midpoint of $B'C'$;
2. Let $A'$ be the intersection between the parallel to $AC$ through $B'$ 
   and the parallel to $AB$ through $C'$;
3. Let $J\in B'C'$ be on the angle bisector of $\widehat{B' A' C'}$;
4. Let $K$ be the symmetric of $J$ with respect to $M$;
5. The wanted line is the parallel to $A'J$ through $K$.

Comment: How did you get P and Q?

Comment: @Lily: by intersecting two lines parallel to $AB$ and $AC$ at the same distance from $AB$ and $AC$.

Comment: or any point P on it, the distance of P from the AB-side equals the distance of P from the AC-side. How do we know that? This might be a stupid question.

Comment: @Lily: that follows from the definition of angle bisector as a locus.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for your help. I learned a lot.